# Nested XML/JSON struct tags, what's the correct way to define structs?

Tags: xml, go, struct, xmlhttprequest

Few of the XML tags are not getting decoded while reading the request body

I have defined my nested struct with both json and xml tags, as I want to use the same schema for request and response in both json and xml.

```
var dataNewTestplans DataTestplan
err := xml.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&dataNewTestplans)
xmlData, _ := xml.Marshal(dataNewTestplans)
fmt.Printf(string(xmlData))
```

DataTestplan struct:

```
type DataTestplan struct {
    Data []Testplan `json:"data" xml:"data"`
}
```

Testplan struct:

```
type Testplan struct {
    Group      string      `json:"group" xml:"group"`
    Name       string      `json:"name" xml:"name"`
    Parameters []Parameter `json:"parameters,omitempty" xml:"parameters,omitempty"`
    Released   bool        `json:"released" xml:"released"`
    Teststeps  []Teststep  `json:"teststeps,omitempty" xml:"teststeps,omitempty"`
    Version    int32       `json:"version" xml:"version"`
}
```

Parameter struct:

```
type Parameter struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"parameters"`
    Comment     string   `json:"comment" xml:"comment"`
    Description string   `json:"description,omitempty" xml:"description,omitempty"`
}
```

Teststep struct:

```
type Teststep struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"teststeps"`
    AslID   string   `json:"aslId,omitempty" xml:"aslID"`
    Bin     int32    `json:"bin,omitempty" xml:"bin"`
}
```

XML sent :

```
<root>
  <data>
    <element>
     <group>TEST</group>
     <name>TEST</name>
     <parameters>
        <element>
           <comment>test</comment>
           <description>test</description>
        </element>
        <element>
           <comment>test1</comment>
        </element>
     </parameters>
     <released>true</released>
     <teststeps>
        <element>
           <bin>32</bin>
        </element>
      </teststeps>
     <version>1</version>
    </element>
  </data>
</root>
```

XML decoded:

```
<DataTestplan>
  <data>
    <group></group>
    <name></name>
    <released>false</released>
    <version>0</version>
    </data>
</DataTestplan>
```

I understand missing tags are most probably because of miss tagging of xml in the struct definition but I am not sure why the decoded information is missing value for tags ? What's the trick with XML and JSON encoding ?

Comment: Just review your XML against your definitions, or fill out a struct fully in Go and export it to XML, then compare that to your input. I see a few things right off the bat; your root element is `root`, not `DataTestPlan`, so that needs an `XMLName` added, and multiple places in the XML where an `element` element appears are not mapped in your structs at all (the struct definitions just ignore it and try to map its children as if it weren't there).

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's "not a struct", it needs to be handled in your mapping. You can't pretend it doesn't exist. E.g. `Parameters` shouldn't be a slice, because there's only one `parameters` element. The `parameters` *contains* a slice of `element` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `>` in the tags.

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal

> If the XML element contains a sub-element whose name matches the
>   prefix of a tag formatted as "a" or "a>b>c", unmarshal will descend
>   into the XML structure looking for elements with the given names, and
>   will map the innermost elements to that struct field. A tag starting
>   with ">" is equivalent to one starting with the field name followed by
>   ">".

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal

> If a field uses a tag "a>b>c", then the element c will be nested
>   inside parent elements a and b. Fields that appear next to each other
>   that name the same parent will be enclosed in one XML element.

For example:

```
type DataTestplan struct {
    Data []Testplan `json:"data" xml:"data>element"`
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/RX3IDI3zubo

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of ">". It was such a minor thing :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a different struct for each tag. You can embed them all in one. For the xml parsing you are missing a few tags. You can avoid some code replication by using the `>` in the xml tag. This will effectively "merge" two elements when you iterate them. Here is an example on a more concise implementation:

```
type Root struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"root"`
    Data    []struct {
        Group      string `json:"group" xml:"group"`
        Name       string `json:"name" xml:"name"`
        Parameters []struct {
            Comment     string `json:"comment" xml:"comment,omitempty"`
            Description string `json:"description" xml:"description,omitempty"`
        } `json:"parameters" xml:"parameters>element"`
        Released  bool `json:"released" xml:"released"`
        Teststeps []struct {
            Bin int32 `json:"bin" xml:"bin"`
        } `xml:"teststeps>element,omitempty"`
        Version int32 `json:"version" xml:"version"`
    } `json:"data" xml:"data>element"`
}
```

By running:

```
var dataNewTestplans DataTestplan
err := xml.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&dataNewTestplans)
xmlData, _ := xml.Marshal(dataNewTestplans)
fmt.Printf(string(xmlData))
```

you get:

```
<root><data><element><group>TEST</group><name>TEST</name><parameters><element><comment>test</comment><description>test</description></element><element><comment>test1</comment></element></parameters><released>true</released><teststeps><element><bin>32</bin></element></teststeps><version>1</version></element></data></root>
```